# When using CollectionView and DataTemplate, how can I display/Use the index/position of my item?

Tags: datatemplate, maui, collectionview

I want a CollectionView with at least 2 labels
1st label is for indexOf the object
2nd label is for a property (name)
as this is a CustomView I only have access to Enumerable ItemsSource. But not the actual List.

```
dataTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
{
    Grid grid = new Grid();

    // Add Single Row
    RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition(this.RowHeight);
    grid.AddRowDefinition(row);

    // Add Column for index
    ColumnDefinition columnIndex = new ColumnDefinition(40);
    grid.AddColumnDefinition(columnIndex);

    // Add Column for name
    ColumnDefinition columnName = new ColumnDefinition(120);
    grid.AddColumnDefinition(columnName);

    Label labelIndex = new Label();
    // What to set as binding?
    // labelIndex.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, ???);
    Grid.SetColumn(labelIndex, 0);
    Grid.SetRow(labelIndex, 0);
    grid.Add(labelIndex);

    Label labelName = new Label();
    label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "name");
    Grid.SetColumn(labelName, 1);
    Grid.SetRow(labelName, 0);
    grid.Add(labelName);

    return grid;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the item model knows what item list it is part of, then can have a property that returns its index:

```cs
public class MyModel
{
  private List<MyModel> Owner;
  public int IndexInt => Owner != null ? Owner.IndexOf(this) : -1;
  public string IndexString => IndexInt.ToString();

  public MyModel(List<MyModel> owner)
  {
    Owner = owner;
  }
}

...
   public List<MyModel> Items;   // The ItemsSource

   // Where you fill ItemsSource
   Items = new List<MyModel>();
   Items.Add(new MyModel(Items));
   ...

...
  labelIndex.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "IndexString");
```